# error(s)_during_evaluation Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]

Eclipse debugger just stopped showing variabile data few days ago it always says error(s)_during_evaluation, i tried increasing the ram in ini , tried to reinstall Eclipse JUNO, and installed Eclipse Helios. Nothing fixed this problem

Comment: Have you checked the program you are debugging, who knows it may be running eclipse crazy :-)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a memory issue you can try increasing the heap size.It is possible to increase heap size allocated by the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) by using command line options.

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size
```

For running from command line you can use

```
java -Xms64m -Xmx256m HelloWorld
```

If you are using the tomcat server, you can change the heap size by going to Eclipse/Run/Run Configuration and select Apache Tomcat/your_server_name/Arguments and under VM arguments section use the following:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms256m -Xmx512M
```

Comment: i dont have any server, but i did change this in ini file for eclipse:  -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m

Comment: i have no console in eclipse

Comment: Do you get any such errors during normal execution? or is it just during debug?

Comment: well evreything works fine its just that when i want to look at any variabile data like how much is the value of int i at the moment it says error(s)_during_evaluation, i can upload a better picture if you want